# Search through multiple public folders

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, public-folders

One of our customers uses their public folders for sending price lists to various customers, they have one main folder with dozens of sub-folders, now everytime someone wants to be deleted from the list and noone knows in which folder he is we have to manually search through every folder, so I was wondering if there is any way to automate this with powershell or the exchange management shell to look through all folders at once?

Comment: No. PF store does not support search folders. Is converting to a shared mailbox an option?

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot delete items with Exchange Powershell, you can get some item detail.

If you call `Get-PublicFolderItemStatistics` on a folder it will output a few details about each item.  This may be enough to at least tell you if a folder contains what you are looking for.

You could then loop thru the selected folder and its children and call `Get-PublicFolderItemStatistics` on each folder.  Then do a `Where-Object` filter on the output to filter out any item that doesn't match your filter.

Sadly though, you're left with either EWS (which has some powershell wrappers) or MAPI to do the deletes.